# nsoperationqueue with priority \ heap

Tags: ios

I'm building an ios app in which I need to control the download of multiple files (images but not just). I will need to prioritize the download of the files, which may change as the user interacts with the application.

I there any method to set the order in which operations are stored in nsoperationqueue. What I'm looking for is a heap data structure with the built in functionality of nsoperationqueue.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `setQueueProperty` method in `NSOperation` that can help you.
From Apple Docs:

> Sets the priority of the operation when used in an operation queue.
>   You should use priority values only as needed to classify the relative
>   priority of non-dependent operations. Priority values should not be
>   used to implement dependency management among different operation
>   objects. If you need to establish dependencies between operations, use
>   the addDependency: method instead.
>
> If you attempt to specify a priority value that does not match one of
>   the defined constants, this method automatically adjusts the value you
>   specify towards the NSOperationQueuePriorityNormal priority, stopping
>   at the first valid constant value. For example, if you specified the
>   value -10, this method would adjust that value to match the
>   NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryLow constant. Similarly, if you specified
>   +10, this method would adjust the value to match the NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryHigh constant.

Read [more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/setQueuePriority%3a)